# how can i show "this pc" icon for all my domain users?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019, group-policy

i have windows server 2019 on my main server and by default windows 10 and 7 (domain computers) doesn't show "this pc" "my computer" when the operating system is installed, i want a quick solution to show this icon for all domain users without having to go to every single pc and make the icon manually for the users

made a gpo with the policy "remove computer icon on disktop" set to disabled hoping the icon would appear for domain users but didn't do it

Comment: Where did you link the GPO?

Comment: Linked it to domain users

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may setup a customized theme with desktop icons using Personalization menu in Control Panel including "This PC" icon as you require then save the theme file then with a GPO setting "Load a specific theme" you may assign the theme file to domain users.
The question is how to send the theme file to computers? The answer is in the same GPO or another define a GPO Preference to add this file to domain computers.
Another question is "will this theme override end user's icons? The answer is no, it will not overwrite.

Edit: Could you chk https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/adding-shortcuts-on-desktop-using-group-policy-preferences-in/ba-p/400260
pls?

Comment: Unable to customize a them to show the icons

Comment: The link you sent me allowed me to do it, thank you